# What happens in linear regression if Y's are not independently sampled?

Tags: regression, self-study, statistical-significance, least-squares

What happens in linear regression $Y\sim X$ when the $Y$'s are not independently sampled and, particularly, may be autocorrelated?

I believe the estimator will still work. But what will happen to the t-stat and the R-squared that measures the goodness of fit?

Any other implications I might not be aware of?

Comment: If the observations are not independent, then the least-squares estimates are still unbiased, however, the standard errors of your estimates can be seriously biased and very misleading, and lead to seriously biased incorrect conclusions from statistical tests.

Comment: @StatsStudent you should post that as an answer. Answers don't need to be technically involved to be helpful and correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ssdecontrol indicated, here's an answer without much explanation:

If the observations are not independent, then the least-squares estimates are still unbiased, however, the standard errors of your estimates can be seriously biased and very misleading, and lead to seriously biased incorrect conclusions from statistical tests.